# Problem while using vertx-guice with vertx 3.8

Tags: promise, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm here because I noticed that vertx-guice 2.3 don't support vertx 3.8 and precisly the using of Promise in verticle start and stop methods.

My project just works fine when I'm using a version of vertx below 3.8 (with Future) but since I made my changes to use promises, my verticle doesn't start anymore.

When I test to remove the use of vertx-guice, it works, but I need it, so this is not a solution

Did someone noticed the same thing ? and how can I fix it ?

Comment: some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem.

Vertx-guice is instanciating his own verticle but use Future instead of Promise. And then call the super verticle start methods with Future.